# JavaScript, Adding 2 variables which i have used parseInt on together outputs like a string

Tags: javascript, html, string, date, parseint

Hi guys i'm having an issue with parseInt variables behaving like Strings.
More than likely something silly i'm doing wrong.
Problem is in the commented area of code

```
function getNewDate()
{
  var dateEntered = document.getElementById('Temp').value;    //input got from a form
  var daysEntered = document.getElementById('Temp1').value ;  //input got from a form 

  var month = dateEntered.charAt(5)+dateEntered.charAt(6);                                            //creating month 
  var date = dateEntered.charAt(8)+dateEntered.charAt(9);                                             //date
  var year = dateEntered.charAt(0)+dateEntered.charAt(1)+dateEntered.charAt(2)+dateEntered.charAt(3); //and year from input
  var newDate = 0 ;
  parseInt(month) ;           //making the below variables integers for calculations
  parseInt(daysEntered) ;
  parseInt(date) ;
  parseInt(newDate) ;
  var newFullDate = "" ;

  if(month == 01)
  {
    newDate = date + daysEntered ;  //if i enter 01/01/2016 as the date
    if(newDate > 31)                //and 5 for days entered
    {                               //when i piece together the newFullDate
      month = 02 ;                  //it outputs like 2016-01-015
      date = 0 ;
      daysEntered = newDate - 31 ;
    }
    else
    {
      newFullDate = ""+year +"-"+"01"+"-"+newDate ;
      document.getElementsByName('output')[0].value= newFullDate;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You need to assign `parseInt(month)` etc in to a variable
as in `var month = parseInt(dateEntered.charAt(5)+dateEntered.charAt(6));`

Comment: Place a breakpoint on the `parseInt(month)` line. After it executes, examine the value of `month`, and you will see that it has not changed. That should give you a good clue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign the values from parseInt to the variables.

```
month = parseInt(month) ;
daysEntered = parseInt(daysEntered) ;
date = parseInt(date) ;
newDate = parseInt(newDate) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

`parseInt()` doesn't directly affect the variable's value. It only returns the result, so you'll need to save it again to the variable.

example:

```
var month = dateEntered.charAt(5)+dateEntered.charAt(6); 
month = parseInt(month);
```

Or you can just do both on the same line:

```
var month = parseInt(dateEntered.charAt(5)+dateEntered.charAt(6));
```